# Linear Transformations: Proving 1 dimensional subspace goes to 1 dimensional

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am having trouble understanding this whole question, and how to prove it.

Let $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ be a linear transformation. Prove that if $L$ is a
$1$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then

$F(L)=\{y\in\mathbb{R}^m: y=F(x)\text{ for some }x\in L\}$

the image of $L$ under $F$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m$ with dimension $1$ or $0$. Hence prove that if the kernel of $F$ is $\{0\}$, then the image of $L$ is a $1$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m$ (and so, in this case, $F$ takes lines in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to lines in $\mathbb{R}^m$).

Answer (score 1):

Since $L$ is one dimensional subspace then it's spanned by one vector say $v$ hence

$$F(L)=\{F(\lambda v)=\lambda F(v),\lambda\in\Bbb R\}$$
hence if $F(v)\ne0$ then $F(L)$ is a one dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^m$ spanned by $F(v)$.

Comment: how about proving that if $Ker(F)$ is $\{0\}$, then the image of L is a $1$-dimensional subspace of ${R}^m$?

Comment: In this case we have $F(v)\ne0$ since $0$ is the only vector   in the kernel of $F$.

Answer (score 0):

The basic point to know here is that is some vectors $v_i$ span a subspace$~L$, and $F$ is any linear map, then their images $F(v_i)$ span the subspace $F(L)$ of the vector space at arrival. Here it is assumed that a single nonzero vector $v_1$ spans $L$, so $F(v_1)$ spans $F(L)$.

Now either $F(v_1)\neq0$, in which case $F(L)$ is spanned by a single nonzero vector and therefore has dimension$~1$, or $F(v_1)=0$ in which case $F(L)=\{0\}$ which has dimension$~0$. The condition $F(v_1)=0$ for the latter case can also be written $v_1\in\ker(F)$, so it cannot happen given that $\ker(F)=\{0\}$ (since $v_1$ was assumed to be nonzero).

Note that $\ker(F)=\{0\}$ is in fact stronger than necessary to get $\dim(F(L))=1$, as for that it suffices to have $\ker(F)\cap L=\{0\}$. But since this is going to be applied to *all* lines $L$, if I understand the question, one can understand why $\ker(F)=\{0\}$ is given.